# If I run the project through the CLI, I get an error, but everything is fine through Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following code of Program.cs:

```cs
using Platform;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(e.ToString());
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"\n{e.TargetSite}");
    }
});

app.Map("/branch", branchBuilder =>
{
    branchBuilder.UseMiddleware<QueryStringMiddleware>();
    branchBuilder.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("branch");
        await next(context);
    });
});
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

And code of `QueryStringMiddleware.cs`:

```cs
namespace Platform
{
    public class QueryStringMiddleware
    {
        private RequestDelegate next;

        public QueryStringMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Get &&
                context.Request.Query["custom"] == "true")
            {
                if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType= "text/plain";
                }

                await context.Response.WriteAsync("class middleware\n");
            }
            await next(context);
        }

        public static async Task Jip(HttpContext context)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("jipjip\n");
        }
    }
}
```

When I make a request to `/branch?custom=true`, then I get this error:

> class middleware
> branchSystem.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.<>c.b__18_0(HttpContext context)
> at Program.<>c.<<$>b__0_3>d.MoveNext() in D:\develop\Platform\Program.cs:line 28
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Platform.QueryStringMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in D:\develop\Platform\Middleware.cs:line 23
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context, PathString matchedPath, PathString remainingPath)
> at Program.<>c.<<$>b__0_0>d.MoveNext() in D:\develop\Platform\Program.cs:line 13
> Void ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(System.String)

But when I do the same thing through Visual Studio, everything goes fine - why is that?

Comment: What is your QueryStringMiddleware supposed to do. It's unlikely that you want to write to the response _and_ pass the request on to the next middleware in the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I test your code with  Visual Studio, and I meet the error like yours.

This error may  be caused by    `await next(context);` in the QueryStringMiddleware,

Try to add  `return;` like below:

```
 await context.Response.WriteAsync("class middleware\n");
 return;
```

**Or** set conditionals to check if the response has started written already.

```
  if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Get &&
      context.Request.Query["custom"] == "true")
  {
      if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
      {
          context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
      }
       await context.Response.WriteAsync("class middleware\n");
      //return;
  }
  if(!context.Response.HasStarted)
  {
      //... Do something here
      await next(context);
  }
```